# Jump animation on first click, normal on second

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating an element where you click on the image, and the content is filled beneath it (kinda like google images search), and I've done it like 90% except the animation jumps on the first click, instead of increasing the height of the content container. And I cannot figure out why is that :\
Once you click on it, and close it, the animation slides down nicely.

I've made the fiddle, since it's pretty big

http://jsfiddle.net/9rc044hg/

The jquery code is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $content = $(".featured_portfolio");
    var $loaded_content = $("#portfolio_content_details");
    var $item_selector = $(".featured_item");
    var $close = $("#close_wrapper");

    $(document).on('click', '#close_wrapper', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $loaded_content.animate({
            height: 0
        }, 500, "linear")
        setTimeout(function () {
            $loaded_content.hide()
        }, 500);
        $('#pointer').hide();
    });

    $content.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $item_selector.on('click', function () {
            leftOffset = parseInt($(this).offset().left + $(this).width() / 2, 10);
            $('#pointer').css({
                'left': leftOffset,
                'display': 'inline-block'
            });

            if (!$(this).hasClass("current")) {
                $(".current").removeClass("current");
                $(this).addClass("current");
            }

            var element_number = $(this).data('number');
            var insert_after = (Math.ceil(element_number / 4) * 4) - 1;

            $loaded_content.detach().insertAfter($item_selector.eq(insert_after));

            var thumbnail = $(this).data('thumbnail');
            var name = $(this).data('name');
            var link_to = $(this).data('link_to');
            var date = $(this).data('date');
            var description = $(this).data('description');
            var cat = $(this).data('cat');
            var client = $(this).data('client');
            var skills = $(this).data('skills');

            $loaded_content.find('.gallery_post_image').html(thumbnail);
            $loaded_content.find('.gallery_post_title').html(name);
            $loaded_content.find('.gallery_post_linkto a').attr("href", link_to);
            $loaded_content.find('.gallery_post_date').html(date);
            $loaded_content.find('.gallery_post_description p').html(description);
            $loaded_content.find('.gallery_post_category .cat_names').html(cat);
            $loaded_content.find('.gallery_post_client .client_names').html(client);
            $loaded_content.find('.gallery_post_skill .skills_names').html(skills);

            setTimeout(function () {
                if (!$(this).hasClass("current")) {
                    $loaded_content.show().animate({
                        height: "560px"
                    }, 500, "linear");
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $loaded_content.offset().top - 300
                    }, 500);
                }
            }, 500);
        });
    });
});
```

I've also tried making it close if you click on the same image, but without luck. I'm adding a class `current` when you click on the image, and when I target that class in the close on click event, nothing happens.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That is because you are injecting your content with javascript, so the browser does not know the height of the element until it has calculated it, which happens on the first display. Try doing the same with your content inside the markup.

Comment: But I'm forcing the height change to 560px, irregardles of the element height. I am suspicious of the attaching of the div too.

Comment: The 560px setting is animated, so it doesn't change anything I guess. Honestly this code doesn't make sense, you're doing everything through JS when you should not. Rebuild a proper container in pure html/css, hide it with css and use javascript only for toggling hide/show states (that makes only a few lines of JS).

Answer (score 2):

Well the answer would be to set the display of your #portfolio_content_details to block and the height to 0 (and you'd have to deal with the initial display of the pointer), generally speaking, your solution is very bad on performance and a very complex solution to a very basic problem.

As suggested by kursus, setting up everything properly before and then just using js to hide and show more information would be a much better way.

A general tip:
Instead of using $(this) several times just define a local variable
var $this = $(this);

Now jQuery won't create a new $(this) every time you execute this function.

Comment: I'll do this, in combination with what kursus said. Since I'm fixing the height and adding classes, I can use css for transitions, this should be better.